# Problemas con el Protocolo CORS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, php7

Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar una peticion a un servidor externo.
La cuestion es que hace ya algún tiempo solucione este problema, pero ahora mismo desconozco si PHP ha actualizado sus librerias y el metodo que yo utilizo está desactualizado:

La peticion que realizo es mediante jQuery usando $.get a un php de otro servidor, esperando que me devuelva un json.

Codigo jQuery (js):

```
$.get ( 'https://example.com/data', { lang : lang }, function ( d ) {}, 'json' );
```

donde la variable lang es solo un parametro para indicar el idioma:

El código PHP del otro servidor:

```
<?php
    
    date_default_timezone_set ('Europe/Madrid');
    header ('Content-Type: application/json');
    header ('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="country.json"');
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header ("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    
    function cors () {
        // Allow from any origin
        if ( isset ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ) {
            header ( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}" );
            header ( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
            header ( 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400' );    // cache for 1 day
        }
        // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS' ) {
            if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) )
                header ( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS" );         
            if ( isset ( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']) )
                header ( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}" );
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    cors ();
    
    if ( !isset ( $_GET ['lang'] ) ) { $lang = 'en'; } else { $lang = $_GET ['lang']; }
    
    $dir = scandir ( __DIR__ . '/lang/' );
    $isLang = 0;
    
    foreach ( $dir as $k => $v ) {
        
        if ( $v == $lang . '.php' ) { $isLang++; }
        
    }
    
    if ( !$isLang ) { $lang = 'en'; }
    
    require __DIR__ . '/lang/' . $lang . '.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/lang/info.php';
    
    if ( isset ( $_GET ['country'] ) ) {
        
        echo json_encode ( [$_GET ['country'] => $_l [$_GET ['country']]] );
        
    } else {
        
        echo json_encode ( $_l );
        
    }
    
?>
```

Esta formula de CORS ya la usé una vez en el pasado y me funcionó, pero por alguna razón ya no me funciona.
Javascript me devuelve el siguiente error:

jq:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/data?lang=es' from origin 'https://sample.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

jq:2 GET https://example.com/data?lang=es net::ERR_FAILED

Si alguien pudiese explicarme cual es el error o que es lo que esta fallando se lo agradeceria.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda varias cosas:

1. EL CORS  es un mecanismo que permite que se puedan solicitar recursos restringidos en una página web desde un dominio diferente del dominio que sirvió el primer recurso.

En tu método de CORS, no veo que estés permitiendole que esa API se pueda consumir desde otra ip de destino, sino desde la misma IP de origen; por lo que te sale el error de CORS.

**SOLUCION:**

1. Modificar los headers, nombrando las IP que puedan consumir esa api, ejemplo:

   ```
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
   header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
   ```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He aplicado la solución que me has facilitado y el problema persiste. Me sigue mostrando que (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin') aún despues de haber incluido la cabecera para que permita la conexión desde cualquier punto.

Comment: Interesante, validaste que esté entrando a este if: if ( isset ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ) {
Lo digo porque no sé si se esté reescribiendo el allow-origin, con una ip diferente. O validaste que sea la misma ip que está permitiendo?

Comment: Todo lo que hubiese dentro de la función cors lo desactivé y deje unicamente las cabeceras que me has facilitado. Cuando entro al archivo que se emite en json, las cabeceras se muestran correctamente, pero cuando solicito el archivo desde un servidor externo, no las reconoce.